# How do I make my App Open Only Once and the next time I open the app it will crash?

Tags: java, android

I want my App to Open Only Once and will not run for the second time I open it

Comment: show code with log cat

Comment: you can make use of sharedprefrences to detect first run and then use android.os.Process.killProcess to kill your app

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya the OP **wants** to crash the app on the second attempt to open it. No need for a logcat, but agreed, show us what you have tried.

Comment: record somewhere that you already launched the app, and check it on the startup. Throw exception when you want the app to crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think SharedPreferences is the better idea and the data is more secure than a file.

Simply copy paste this to your onCreate().

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Boolean expired= sharedPref.getBoolean("expired", false);

if (expired){
    throw new RuntimeException("Custom crash");
}

//Make it expierd
SharedPreferences pref=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putBoolean("expired", true);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: SharedPreference sharedPref = getActivty().getPreference)...got Red Squigly line

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a file on the phone (probably somewhere hidden) the first time the app is opened, and then do something like this in the `onCreate`:

```
File file = new File("path/to/file);
if(file.exists()) {
    throw new RuntimeException("This is a crash"); //Let app crash
}
```